# Getting a trainer to work on a LAN server in World in Conflict : Soviet Assault?

Tags: world-in-conflict-soviet-assault

So my friend and  I got the latest version 1.011, and wanted to play a LAN game using a trainer for some extra fun.

Problem is, only the admin/host can activate the trainer and play normally. While anyone else who joins can still activate the trainer, but wont be able to deploy any units at all ... so the trainer works for unlimited resources but they cannot be used to deploy units ..

The glitch is annoying and was wondering if anyone figured out a way to fix this ?

Comment: I would not call "preventing clients from cheating" a "glitch"...

Comment: Its a lan game with friends, we're all doing it .. Its not cheating this way.